# Regex with a wildcard text string

Tags: regex, validation, filepattern

I have 2 file patterns

- VCSTrades_yyyymmdd_OMEGA.csv
- VCSPositions_yyyymmdd_OMEGA.csv

I was hoping to use the 1 regex but i'm having difficulty with anything after the first underscore

This is what i thought would work

`VCS([a-zA-Z]*$)_[0-9]{8}_OMEGA.csv`

Please help

Comment: Remove that `$`. It means "end of string", and it won't match anything after it.

Comment: `VCS([a-zA-Z]*)_[0-9]{8}_OMEGA[.]csv` ..in regex universe `.` matches anything(_so escape it or add it to character class_) and `$` marks end of string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete regex that matches what you're looking for and nothing but:

`\AVCS(Trades|Positions)_[0-9]{8}_OMEGA\.csv\Z`

If this pattern will occur within a line of text, remove the `\A` and `\Z` from the beginning and end, respectively.

Also, if you want to test out regexes, I recommend a website like [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) - it tests your regex in real-time against any text you put in the box.

Comment: `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a line, not the beginning and end of the entire string. This means that `"ZOMG\nVCSTrades_00000000_OMEGA.csv\nKTHX"` will match your regex. `\A` and `\Z` are better suited.